# Including @Model properties in jquery post to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I just am getting started with asp.net / mvc3 / jquery etc.  I have a jquery datepicker and what I have working so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ImplementationStart').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/request/update/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'Date': date
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And in my Controller, I have this method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(DateTime date)
    {
```

It looks like my date gets passed in.  What I want to do, is update the appropriate model object from the .cshtml page where the date picker is.  On that page, I display the @Model properties, but I wasn't sure how to pass back the @Model.Request.ID with my post to my controller.  Thanks.

Comment: Just place the Id inside of input:hidden the binder will attach it to the model, that way you get a nice object to work with , instead of DateTime you place some model object like Person or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the date because you are sending it explicitly in the `ajax` `post`. Try:

```
 data: {
         'Date': date,
         'ModelId':'@Model.Id'
        },
```

If you want the id to be available in the form post contain it in the hidden field like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
```

where `x` refers to your model. If the first solution doesn't work for you keep the id in the hidden field and before sending the ajax call get the val of the hidden field and then send it in the ajax post.